# Parsing BeautifulSoup html tag

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I need to parse an HTML file using BeautifulSoup. The HTML looks like that:

```
    <div class="entry_container">

       <div class="entry lang_en-gb" id="turn-over_1">   
          <span class="inline">
             <h1 class="hwd">turn over</h1>
          </span>
          <div class="hom" id="turn-over_1.1">
             <span class="gramGrp"><span class="pos">intransitive verb</span></span>
             <div class="sense"><span class="bold">1 </span><span class="gramGrp"><span class="colloc"><span>[</span>person<span>]</span></span></span><span class="lbl"><span> (</span>in bed<span>)</span></span><span> </span><span class="cit lang_fr"><span class="quote">se retourner</span></span><span class="cit" id="turn-over_1.2"><span>;   </span></span></div>

             <div class="sense"><span> <br/></span><span class="bold">2 </span><span class="gramGrp"><span class="colloc"><span>[</span>car<span>]</span></span></span><span> </span><span class="cit lang_fr"><span class="quote">se retourner</span></span><span>, </span><span class="cit lang_fr"><span class="quote">faire un tonneau</span></span><span class="cit" id="turn-over_1.3"><span>;   </span></span></div>

             <div class="sense"><span> <br/></span><span class="bold">3 </span><span class="lbl"><span>(= </span>switch TV channels<span>)</span></span><span> </span><span class="cit lang_fr"><span class="quote">changer de chaîne</span></span><span class="cit" id="turn-over_1.4"><span>;   </span></span></div>

          </div>

          <div class="hom" id="turn-over_1.5">
             <span> <br/>▶ </span><span class="gramGrp"><span class="pos">transitive verb</span></span>
             <div class="sense">
                <span class="bold">1 </span>
                <div class="sense"><span class="bold">   a </span><span class="gramGrp"><span class="colloc"><span>[</span><span>+ </span>object<span>]</span></span></span><span> </span><span class="cit lang_fr"><span class="quote">retourner</span></span><span class="cit" id="turn-over_1.6"><span>;   </span></span></div>

                <div class="sense"><span class="bold">   b </span><span class="gramGrp"><span class="colloc"><span>[</span><span>+ </span>page<span>]</span></span></span><span> </span><span class="cit lang_fr"><span class="quote">tourner</span></span></div>

                <div class="sense"><span class="bold">   c </span><span class="gramGrp"><span class="colloc"><span>[</span><span>+ </span>tape<span>]</span></span></span><span> </span><span class="cit lang_fr"><span class="quote">changer de face</span></span><span class="cit" id="turn-over_1.7"><span>;   </span></span></div>

             </div>

             <div class="sense"><span> <br/></span><span class="bold">2 </span><span class="lbl"><span>(= </span>hand over<span>)</span></span><span> </span><span class="cit lang_fr"><span class="quote">remettre</span></span><span class="cit" id="turn-over_1.8"><span>;   </span></span><span class="cit" id="turn-over_1.9"><span>;   </span></span></div>

          </div>      
       </div>

    </div>
```

I need to retrieve the pos (`span class="pos"`) and the sense (each `<div class="sense">`) of each `div class="hom"`

The results of parsing may look like this:

[image]

For now, I've try this code:

```
for gramGrp in entryContentHTML.find_all('div',attrs={"class":u"hom"}):
  for pos in gramGrp.find('span',attrs={"class":u"gramGrp"}).find('span',attrs={"class":u"pos"}):
    print pos
```

But the output is:

```
intransitive verb
intransitive verb
transitive verb
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will have to tidy the output but this will get what you need:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
soup = BeautifulSoup(html)

res= (["\n".join(s.strip() for s in x.text.splitlines()).replace(";","") for x in     soup.find_all("div", {"class":"hom"})])
print("\n".join(res))


intransitive verb
1 [person] (in bed) se retourner
2 [car] se retourner, faire un tonneau
3 (= switch TV channels) changer de chaîne

▶ transitive verb

1
a [+ object] retourner
b [+ page] tourner
c [+ tape] changer de face

2 (= hand over) remettre
```